# WebApplicationFactory is running the Api with the old IConnectionMultiplexer which fails to connect instead of first overriding configuration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, integration-testing

I'm working on an integration test for a Web API which communicates through Redis, so I tried to replace the Redis Server with a containerized one and run some tests.

The issue is that it is first running the Api with project's `appsettings.Development.json` configuration and the old `IConnectionMultiplexer` instance which obviously won't connect because the hostname is offline. The question is how do I make it run the project with the new `IConnectionMultiplexer` that uses the containerized Redis Server? Basically the sequence is wrong there. What I did is more like run the old `IConnectionMultiplexer` and replace it with the new one but it wouldn't connect to the old one, so that exception prevents me from continuing. I commented the line of code where it throws the exception but as I said it's obvious because it's first running the Api with the old configuration instead of first overriding the configuration and then running the Api.

I could have done something like the following but I'm DI'ing other services based on configuration as well, meaning I ***must*** override the configuration first and ***then run*** the actual API code.

```cs
try
{
    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConfig.Host);
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(redis);
}
catch
{
    // We discard that service if it's unable to connect
}
```

### Api

```cs
public static class RedisConnectionConfiguration
{
    public static void AddRedisConnection(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration config)
    {
        var redisConfig = config.GetSection("Redis").Get<RedisConfiguration>();

        serviceCollection.AddHostedService<RedisSubscription>();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(redisConfig);
        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConfig.Host); // This fails because it didn't override Redis:Host
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(redis);
    }
}
```

### Integration tests

```cs
public class OrderManagerApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<IApiMarker>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private const string Password = "Test1234!";

    private readonly TestcontainersContainer _redisContainer;
    private readonly int _externalPort = Random.Shared.Next(10_000, 60_000);

    public OrderManagerApiFactory()
    {
        _redisContainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
            .WithImage("redis:alpine")
            .WithEnvironment("REDIS_PASSWORD", Password)
            .WithPortBinding(_externalPort, 6379)
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(6379))
            .Build();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");

        builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
        });

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Redis:Host", $"localhost:{_externalPort},password={Password},allowAdmin=true" },
                { "Redis:Channels:Main", "main:new:order" },
            });
        });

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(IConnectionMultiplexer));
            services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(_ =>
                ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"localhost:{_externalPort},password={Password},allowAdmin=true"));
        });
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _redisContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _redisContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class OrderManagerTests : IClassFixture<OrderManagerApiFactory>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly OrderManagerApiFactory _apiFactory;

    public OrderManagerTests(OrderManagerApiFactory apiFactory)
    {
        _apiFactory = apiFactory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var configuration = _apiFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var redis = _apiFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IConnectionMultiplexer>();
        var channel = configuration.GetValue<string>("Redis:Channels:Main");

        // Act
        await redis.GetSubscriber().PublishAsync(channel, "ping");

        // Assert
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

> If you override `WebApplicationFactory<T>.CreateHost()` and call `IHostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration()` before calling `base.CreateHost()` the configuration you add will be visible between `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` and `builder.Build()`.

The following two links might help someone:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37680
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9275

```cs
public sealed class OrderManagerApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<IApiMarker>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private const string Password = "Test1234!";
    private const int ExternalPort = 7777; // Random.Shared.Next(10_000, 60_000);

    private readonly TestcontainersContainer _redisContainer;

    public OrderManagerApiFactory()
    {
        _redisContainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
            .WithImage("redis:alpine")
            .WithEnvironment("REDIS_PASSWORD", Password)
            .WithPortBinding(ExternalPort, 6379)
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(6379))
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _redisContainer.StartAsync();
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _redisContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
            config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Redis:Host", $"localhost:{ExternalPort},password={Password},allowAdmin=true"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Redis:Channels:Main", "main:new:order")
            }));

        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```